# i can't get a variable in scale tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to take a variable with a tkinter scale and print it.
But it always prints 0.0.
For some reason I have to use the MSE function.

```
from tkinter import *
def MSE():
    MSEroot= Tk()
    def MSEmenu(MSEnum):
        if MSEnum==1:
            var = DoubleVar()
            scale = Scale(MSEroot, variable=var,from_=0, to=1, resolution=0.01).grid()

           btngetmseExample = Button(MSEroot, padx=16, pady=16,text='get value',command=lambda: Mseget()).grid(row=2, column=0)
    def Mseget():
        print(var.get())

    btnmseExamole= Button(MSEroot, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('arial', 15, 'bold'), text='MSE Example',
                  command= lambda:MSEmenu(1)).grid(row=0, column=0)

    MSEroot.mainloop()
root = Tk()

btnmsemape = Button(root, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('arial', 15, 'bold'), text='MSE & MAPE',
                  command= lambda:MSE()).grid(row=0, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `var` is a *local variable* inside `MSEmenu()`; it ceases to exist at the end of that function, and cannot be accessed anywhere else in the program.  Note that calling `Tk()` more than once causes all sorts of problems with Tkinter Vars, it would be better to use `Toplevel()` to create additional windows.

Comment: Apart from changing `Tk()` to `Toplevel()` inside `MSE()`, you can move `var = DoubleVar()` out of `MSEmenu()` (move after `MSEroot = Toplevel()`.